# How to determine how much gas to use

Tags: ethers.js

I've been trying to make a call to a contract function however everytime I get:

```
insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost
```

I have 0.024 ETH in the wallet I am using. Here's the code:

```
var wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey,provider);
const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(CAddress, CABI, wallet);

const tx = {
        from: fromAddress,
        gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10000000", 'gwei'),
        gasLimit: 29970676,
        nonce: 4055,
}
contractInstance.someFunc(tx).then((tx)=> {
    console.log(tx)
    tx.wait().then(console.log)
})
```

Would anybody know what is the correct `gasLimit` and `gasPrice` that I need to input? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The standard gas limit is 21,000 units, while the gas price is 200 gwei. The total fee is calculated as: (gas units (limit) x gas price per unit). In this example, that would equal: 21,000 x 200 = 4,200,000 gwei, or 0.0042 ETH.

Comment: in my case what should gasPrice and gasLimit be?

Comment: in your case, you can set gasLimit: 1000000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("20", 'gwei').

Comment: Thanks! so I set both of those: `gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("200", 'gwei'),` and `gasLimit: 100000,` the transaction didn't throw an error however transaction never completes when I wait  `tx.wait()`.

Comment: try again with 20 gwei and 1,000,000

Comment: { type: 2, chainId: 1, nonce: 4057, gasPrice: null, gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x0f4240', _isBigNumber: true }, to: '0xC1E088fC1323b20BCBee9bd1B9fC9546db5624C5', value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true }, data: '0xfc06d2a6', accessList: [], hash: '0x678256f2b12414be5e544d29d7dcf3c55bf56cc2d0fdb69aa4aee321a97f05a1', from: '0x05Dc8E95a479dDA8C8Fc5a27Eb825f5042048937', confirmations: 0}

Comment: still doesn't resolve when i call await `tx.wait()` also notice that `gasPrice` is null. What might be the reason?

Comment: also I don;'t see the transaction in the mempool.

Comment: so weird, did you set gasPrice as ethers.utils.parseUnits("20", 'gwei')?

Comment: yup `gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("20", 'gwei')`

Comment: not sure, but it seems you made a mistake on provider, fromAddress, or nonce value.

Answer (score 0):

The gas consumed by an application [before the London upgrade¹](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#pre-london) was calculated as follows:

`totalFees = gasLimit * gasPrice (in Wei).`

In your case this would be:

```
gasLimit = 30 mio.
gasPrice = 10 million (gwei) 
totalFees = 300 million ether
```

what exceeds your balance.
See [this source](https://gwei.io/) for converting `Gwei => Wei`.

The easiest way is just to use the default value provided by ethers. They should work out in most cases.

Or alternatively you could use the [current gas price](https://etherscan.io/gastracker)
and multiply it with the gas used by your transactions (the majoriy of tx use less than 1M gas). You can pay a bit more since any additional gas is refunded.

¹The new formula should not change much here

Comment: I still get an error insuficient funds